# could not find gem when i run "rails new blogs"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have create new project and get this error in rails

```
here@jaskaran:/var/www/blogs$ rails new blogs
Could not find gem 'sqlite3 (>= 0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

How i can solve that ?

Comment: How you tried to solve the problem? bring attempts.

Comment: when i run bundle install i am also getting error

Comment: Have you got ruby installed? Can you give us an overview of your environment / setup?

Comment: http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/

Comment: What error are you getting when running `bundle install`?